# Windows GNU Make breaks POSIX color codes in certain cases, but why?

Tags: windows, makefile, gnu, googletest, output-formatting

I have some problem with a GNU make project on Windows 10.
I'm trying to add google unit tests in my Makefile and I started to experiment with targets like these:

```
utest_compile:
 @echo Compile unit test
 g++ -o Utest.exe $(COMPILE_FLAGS) $(SOURCES)
 @echo Compile finished!

utest_run:
 @echo Running unit tests
 Utest.exe --gtest_color="yes"
 @echo Run finished!

utest: utest_compile utest_run
```

Running `utest_complie` and `utest_run` separately works perfectly, but when trying to run `utest`, the color codes in the output somehow get all messed up, like printing `[0;32m[       OK ] [mDummytest` in default color instead of printing `[       OK ] Dummytest`  in green.

I've tried to search how GNU make parses output and passes it around, especially regarding the phony targets and their dependencies, but any rule I could find seems not to apply in this case. (e.g. rules when storing output in variable, or when redirecting into a file, etc.)

Do you know what kind of parsing/formatting rules apply here, and how to save the color codes from being corrupted?

**EDIT**
Meanwhile I found out the following:
This works fine (prints colored text):

```
utest: utest_compile
    @echo Run unit tests...
    -$(TARGET_DIR)/UTest.exe --gtest_color="yes" > ut.log
    @echo Result:
    @tail -n 1 ut.log
    @echo Unit test execution finished.
```

But this fails (prints uncolored fuzzy text):

```
utest: utest_compile
    @echo Run unit tests...
    $(RM) -f ut.log
    -$(TARGET_DIR)/UTest.exe --gtest_color="yes" > ut.log
    @echo Result:
    @tail -n 1 ut.log
    @echo Unit test execution finished.
```

My suspicion is that the extra line - using rm - is probably switching between terminal modes. I'm using the Windows 10 built in linux terminal interpreter, which is most likely still in beta, so it can explain the issue, but I still don't know the actual details here, and I would be glad for any info.

Comment: Are you invoking make with the `-j` option?

Comment: Nope, it is a sequential build. I doubt it would work with any parallel jobs started, as the 'run' target is quite heavily depends on the exe made by the 'compile' target.

Comment: It looks like something is resetting the terminal settings, so that control characters are no longer being interpreted as vt100 or whatever terminal sequences but instead are being printed.  The behavior of windows terminals is a dark mystery to me so I'm afraid I won't be able to help.  You should definitely add a Windows tag to your question as I suspect that it's related to Windows and wouldn't happen on POSIX-based systems (certainly I was not able to reproduce it on GNU/Linux).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I added the windows tag as well.